# chrome.tabs.create Infinite loop?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to open a local html page in a new tab by using `chrome.tabs.create` and it ended up in an infinite loop, opening the same tab over and over again until I spam cmd+w (close tab shortcut for Mac) or till Chrome crashes. It works fine if I open a new URL instead of a local html file.

`chrome.tabs.create({url: "test.html"});` ends up in infinite loop.
`chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.google.com/"});` works fine.

What gives?

Comment: You need to show more of your code than that.

Comment: [url ( optional string )
The URL to navigate the tab to initially. Fully-qualified URLs must include a scheme (i.e. 'http://www.google.com', not 'www.google.com'). **Relative URLs will be relative to the current page within the extension.** Defaults to the New Tab Page.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)

Comment: oddly I just had a weird issue where i hit command+T in Chrome and it kept opening new tabs...

Answer (score 0):

You can't load this file directly. Try this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL("test.html")});
```